# Can Darknet be Integrated with Tensorflow and tfx?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, cnn, yolo

Tensorflow and Darknet are deep learning frameworks that work and are configured. Can Darknet be Integrated differently? Is there any framework or way to integrate Darknet within a tfx pipeline, for both inferencing and training models? I do work with both frameworks and need to unify this work. For example, I may train my model in Darknet and make all the inference work in Tensorflow or vice versa.

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow, It's a tensorflow implementation of YOLO.

Comment: @JavierTG This is not what I am asking about.